# How to get product collection by Widget's Encoded Conditions in Magento 2.3.5

Tags: php-7, widget, related-products, magento2.3.5-p1, conditions-serialized

I have a widget with conditions_encoded (including Multiple Category Ids, Multiple SKUs) in one section of the admin panel.

The requirement is to show the product list with custom pagination, custom mode, sorting, filter option by Widget's encoded condition(s) Multiple Category Ids, Multiple SKU in custom page.

I can't understand how to render the encoded conditions array of Multiple Category Ids and Multiple SKU that are given as the condition(s) in the widget and how to show the product collection with related pagination, mode, and also filter option in the left panel like category product list page.

The `conditions_encoded` screenshot has been attached here. It will be helpful if it has been given a proper solution or clue.

Thank You.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a widget for arbitrary product lists (as mentioned by @Nits). If you insert the widget on any CMS page or block and turn off the WYSIWYG editor ("Hide editor" button), you can see how the parameters look like.

For example, I created the widget with the condition "category = 4", showing five products:

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" title="My products" products_count="5" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:12:`category_ids`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`==`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`4`;]]"}}
```

From that you can see that the class is Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList and you can create it programmatically as follows:

```
$productsBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList::class);
$productsBlock->setTitle("My products");
$productsBlock->setProductsCount(5);
$productsBlock->setTemplate("product/widget/content/grid.phtml");
$productsBlock->setConditionsEncoded("a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:12:`category_ids`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`==`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`4`;]]");
```

But "conditions_encoded" is a serialized array (with some characters replaced for WYSIWYG compatibility). This serialized array is difficult to construct manually, but luckily you can also use "conditions" with the unserialized value instead in PHP code. So you can replace the last line from above with:

```
$productsBlock->setConditions(
    [
        1 => [
            'type' => \Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine::class,
            'aggregator' => 'all',
            'value' => '1',
            'new_child' => '',
        ],
        '1-1' => [
            'type' => \Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition\Product::class,
            'attribute' => 'category_ids',
            'operator' => '==',
            'value' => '4',
        ]
    ]
);
```

Then output:

> echo $productsBlock->toHtml();